# How to filter the filtered?

Tags: jquery, checkbox, filter

The idea is simple, I'm using checkboxes to filter a list but I can't work out how to filter the results.

For example, checkbox for horror movies returns all the movies with a class of "horror", but I can't work out how to then continue to filter for a given day "today, weekdays or weekends" with only the results from the visible horror results. When clicking on a day type I'm returned ALL results that have that day type class.

Have a look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/satrop/octyzw2z/)

Here is the magic that needs a little help.

```
$('.tags').find('input:checkbox').on('click', function() {
  $('.results > div').hide();

  $('.tags').find('input:checked').each(function() {
    $('.results > div.' + $(this).attr('rel')).addClass('active').show();
  });

  $('input.dayCheck').on('change', function() {
    $('input.dayCheck').not(this).prop('checked', false);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify your code by using the checked checkboxes to build a selector for the classes of the chosen elements.

Note that you should hook to the `change` event to do this so that the code works for those who navigate using the keyboard only.

```
$('.tags input:checkbox').on('change', function() {
    var classString = $('.tags :checkbox:checked').map(function() {
        return $(this).data('rel');
    }).get().join('.');

    var $divs = $('.results > div').toggle(classString == '');       
    if (classString != '')
        $divs.filter('.' + classString).show();
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/octyzw2z/3/)

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you very much for you help, your time and your advice - hook on `change` not `click`. Really to appreciate it!

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 0):

You can get the checked inputs `rel` as an array, then you can join them using `.` for getting selector for class.

```
$('.tags').find('input:checkbox').on('click', function() {
  $('.results > div').hide();
  if($(this).hasClass('dayCheck'))
      $('input.dayCheck').not(this).prop('checked', false);
  classes = $('.tags').find('input:checked').map(function(){
    return $(this).attr('rel');
  }).get();
  selector = classes.length ? '.' + classes.join('.') : '';
  $('.results > div' + selector).addClass('active').show();
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/o14uwrnb/4/)

Comment: And thank you for you help and time! This also worked.